# how to get my navigation button stay active

Tags: html, css, navigation

Can't get my navigation to stay active using html and css. It just light up but does not stay active when pressed. What am I missing?

How do I make it stay active when pressed? Really need the help fast! Sorry for my bad code, I'm new to coding.

How do I type the active class? I tried to, but it did not work.

**HTML**

```
<div id="apaknavig">
  <div id="menu2">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="uznemums.html">Uzņēmums</a></li>
      <li><a href="kontakti.html">kontakti</a></li>    
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#apaknavig {
  Width: 200px;
  height: 604px;
  top:-613px;
  position:relative;
  font:14px Arial;
  color:black;      
  float:left;
  right:35px;
  text-indent:12px;
  display: block;
  line-height:30px;
}

#menu2 ul{
  list-style:none;
  float: left;
  font:14px Arial;
  color:black;  
  right:90px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align:left; width:10px;
  display: block;
  line-height:30px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

#menu2 a{
  background-image: url(bildes/apak_navig.png);
  display:block;
  width: 196px;
  height:34px;
  font:14px Arial;
  color:black;  
  float:left;
  right:90px;
  text-decoration:none;
  display: block;
  line-height:30px;
  margin-bottom:3px;
}

#menu2 a:hover{
  background-image: url(bildes/apak_navig_green.png);
  color:white;
  font:14px Arial;
  color:black;  
  text-decoration:none;
  display: block;
  line-height:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change `#menu2 a:hover{` to `#menu2 a:hover, #menu2 a:active {`.

You just have to add `#menu2 a:active` to the CSS.

```
#menu2 a:hover,#menu2 a:active{
  background-image: url(bildes/apak_navig_green.png);
  color:white;
  font:14px Arial;
  color:black;  
  text-decoration:none;
  display: block;
  line-height:30px;
}
```

I tried it but it just does not work. It continues to just hover, but does not stay active when I press it.

Comment: Then, add `active` to the `#menu2 a` rule: `#menu2 a, #menu2 a:active{`.